# Application pool stops when attempting to run exe (server side) using ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

```
namespace RunMyExe
{
    public partial class runEXE: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            AppDomain sandbox = AppDomain.CreateDomain("sandbox");
            try
            {

                string exeFile = Request.MapPath("myEXE.exe");
                sandbox.ExecuteAssembly(exeFile);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string error = ex.Message;
                lblerror.Text = error;

            }
        }


    }
}
```

I publish this aspx page/site on IIS7 on windows2008r2, when I browse the URL of the published page eg. https://myserver/runEXE.aspx, the exe does run as I can verify the output, but I get this on the browser  "This web page is not available ERR_INVALID_HANDLE" and the application pool stops running, I have to go to the server and start the application pool every time I attempt to browse this URL.

Comment: What is logged in the event viewer

Comment: a warning is logged 
source:WAS
Details:A process serving application pool 'myAppPool' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '1234'. The process exit code was '0x0'.

Comment: Normally when app pool crashes an error is logged as well. Are you sure there is no error before this warning?

Comment: Try running the app pool as network service or local system account. Right click on app pool - advanced settings. Instated of app pool identity select network service or local system (in fact try with both)

Comment: I rechecked, there is no error logged, only a warning. I tried running the appPool as "networkservice", "local system" and "Application Pool Identity" and I get the same result everytime. i have tried other basic things like giving full control to the relevant app pool user. restarting the application pool.

Comment: We need to narrow down this problem. Add an html page to the root folder - then try browsing it. Also try to reinstall asp.net using aspnet_regiis command

Comment: I couldnt find the root cause of the issue, so changed the approach to achieve this. The event now just sets a flag marking an exe to be run. I deployed another service on the server that keeps watching for this flag and launches it to perform the background process.